# Optimising a table-based interpolation loop

Tags: c, graphics, interpolation, lookup-tables

The part of my program that takes most of the CPU time is the 2D loop that follows. What it does is fill a 512x512 RGB image `output` using a 512x512 table `lut`, each entry pointing to 4 entries in the one dimensional ~4000 entry RGB `input` buffer as well as indicating the respective fixed point weights of each of those input pixels. The goal of this is to wrap a 1D buffer into a 2D spiral for visualisation, which is why it uses a LUT as those indices and weights are not trivial to compute.

`kV` is 512 (the dimensions of the output image and LUT), every member of every struct is a `uint16_t` (`.r` `.g` and `.b` included, `lut`'s struct also contains two `double` values) and the other values are just various integer offsets and what not.

```
for (iy=0; iy<kV; iy++)
    {
        for (ix=0; ix<kV; ix++)
        {
            output[(iy+ci->vy) * ci->kW + ix+ci->vx].r = (
                input[lut[iy*kV+ix].spos0].r * lut[iy*kV+ix].w0 + 
                input[lut[iy*kV+ix].spos1].r * lut[iy*kV+ix].w1 + 
                input[lut[iy*kV+ix].spos2].r * lut[iy*kV+ix].w2 + 
                input[lut[iy*kV+ix].spos3].r * lut[iy*kV+ix].w3) >> 15;
            output[(iy+ci->vy) * ci->kW + ix+ci->vx].g = (
                input[lut[iy*kV+ix].spos0].g * lut[iy*kV+ix].w0 + 
                input[lut[iy*kV+ix].spos1].g * lut[iy*kV+ix].w1 + 
                input[lut[iy*kV+ix].spos2].g * lut[iy*kV+ix].w2 + 
                input[lut[iy*kV+ix].spos3].g * lut[iy*kV+ix].w3) >> 15;
            output[(iy+ci->vy) * ci->kW + ix+ci->vx].b = (
                input[lut[iy*kV+ix].spos0].b * lut[iy*kV+ix].w0 + 
                input[lut[iy*kV+ix].spos1].b * lut[iy*kV+ix].w1 + 
                input[lut[iy*kV+ix].spos2].b * lut[iy*kV+ix].w2 + 
                input[lut[iy*kV+ix].spos3].b * lut[iy*kV+ix].w3) >> 15;
        }
    }
```

Pretty simple but I'm pretty sure something's done wrong or could be done more efficiently. I get an average of about 66 cycles for each pixel (with VS2010 and full optimisation), given the simplicity of what this does I'd think it could get better than that. Or not?

**Edit**: This is what I get with the suggested edits, 36 cycles instead of 66, hurray! Can we do better?

```
    for (iy=0; iy<kV; iy++)
    {
        iykv = iy*kV;
        col = (iy+ci->vy) * ci->kW;
        for (ix=0; ix<kV; ix++)
        {
            lutv = lut[iykv+ix];
            outptr = &output[col + ix+ci->vx]
            outptr->r = (
                input[lutv.spos0].r * lutv.w0 + 
                input[lutv.spos1].r * lutv.w1 + 
                input[lutv.spos2].r * lutv.w2 + 
                input[lutv.spos3].r * lutv.w3) >> 15;
            outptr->g = (
                input[lutv.spos0].g * lutv.w0 + 
                input[lutv.spos1].g * lutv.w1 + 
                input[lutv.spos2].g * lutv.w2 + 
                input[lutv.spos3].g * lutv.w3) >> 15;
            outptr->b = (
                input[lutv.spos0].b * lutv.w0 + 
                input[lutv.spos1].b * lutv.w1 + 
                input[lutv.spos2].b * lutv.w2 + 
                input[lutv.spos3].b * lutv.w3) >> 15;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know about optimization yet, but you could make this a **lot** easier to read simply by factoring out some of the common calculations into intermediate variables.

Comment: you are doing lookup `output[(iy+ci->vy) * ci->kW + ix+ci->vx]` three times instead of once, lookup `lut[iy*kV+ix]` twelve times instead of once, and lookup `input[lut[iy*kV+ix].spos<0,1,2,3>]` 3 times instead of once (for each `spos`)  I would recommend `var temp_pix = output[(iy+ci->vy) * ci->kW + ix+ci->vx]; var temp_lut = lut[iy*kV+ix]; ` et cetera. then assign the values for r, g, b with multiplication from your temp vars.

Comment: Alright thanks I'll try that (though I assumed the compiler might optimise those out? I hope I turn out to be wrong)! Would it be better to use a pointer for the output or rather an intermediary variable and then assign the contents of the variable to the buffer?

Comment: Since these are structs there shouldn't be any sizable performance difference between pointer or reference variables.

Comment: @MichelRouzic: A decent compiler should probably render these into very similar code either way (although you could just try both and compare the resulting assembler).

Comment: Alright, I guess I was really wrong to assume the compiler would just optimise out all the lookups, I did the suggested changes and now it's about 78% faster! I've appended the changed code to the post, if you see anything else worth trying let me know. Thanks!

Comment: It goes slightly (about 1 cycle) faster when using directly a pointer to `output[...]` than when doing `output[...]=outv`, but not for inputs. So pointers for writing and copies for reading seems best.

Comment: And interestingly it seems to matter quite a bit (3 or 4 cycles) if I assign lutv before outptr or not. Probably some pipeline issue where it doesn't like needing lutv right after computing it?

Answer (score 0):

You should do the same with `input[lutv.spos0]`, `input[lutv.spos1]`, `input[lutv.spos2]` and `input[lutv.spos3]`.

These should be pointers, since you use a property of the object instead of the object itself.

Also, some pretty good optimization advice offered [here](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~cwyman/classes/spring07-22C251/handouts/optimize.pdf).

Comment: Oh yeah right, I forgot that they repeat for each colour channel. Thanks! By the way, no reason for me to put lutv.w0 and such into their own variables (they're `uint16_t`s in a struct), right?

Comment: those look like direct references to me. unless you have something going on in lutv that uses an array each time you call those.

Comment: Oddly enough this is slightly (~6%) slower that way, pretty weird. It works better if I make them pointers instead of copied values, and then it doesn't make much of a difference with the way it was before! I'll try turning some of the other stuff into pointers to see if it's faster too.